# Arguments as functions with variable number of arguments

Tags: go

How can I pass in Golang a function as an argument that can have potentially multiple arguments, e.g. `fmt.Printf`?

The first problem is that one has to define the type of the function to be passed first.

```
type FunctionWithVariableArgumentLength func(s string, object1 type1, ..., objectn typen)
```

The second problem is that one does not know what types the arguments in the list may have, like in `fmt.Printf`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a prototype as for other functions : http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Printf

So you can define your function accepting a function as argument like this :

```
func exe(f func(string, ...interface{}) (int, error)) {
    f("test %d", 23)
}
func main() {
    exe(fmt.Printf)
}
```

[Demonstration](http://play.golang.org/p/AUMfeeGDOO)

Answer (score 2):

You would use a similar signature as the one for [`fmt.Printf`](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Printf)

```
func yourFunction(a ...interface{})
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer the 1st part: writing functions with a variable number of arguments.

```
// sums returns the total of a variable number of arguments
func sum(numbers ...int) total int {
    total = 0
    for _, n := range numbers {
        total += n
    }
    return total
}
```

The 2nd Part is harder but the function definition looks like:

```
func doVarArgs(fmt string, a ...interface{}) {
```

The variable `a` contains a slice of values of the type `interface{}`. You then iterate over the slice pulling each argument and using the package "reflect" to query the type of each argument.

See http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/ for a full explanation.